# ImageView showing under app title and not below it

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I have added an ImageView in my android app. The half image is showing under the App title bar (bar which shows app name) instead of showing below the App title bar. Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TopLevelActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_options"
        android:entries="@array/options"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to your LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Add android:paddingTop to imageview hope this may help you

Comment: I already did that but thats just a work around I need a proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to set your theme defiened in the Manifest to :

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

Then add this code to your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FAFAFA">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="Your App Title"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_options"
        android:entries="@array/options"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[View post on imgur.com](//imgur.com/XVgt4XP)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have uploaded the screenshot http://imgur.com/XVgt4XP